# Downloaded docx files corrupt in Chrome and IE (Railo/Coldfusion)

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, coldfusion, railo

I have had the same 'working' code for quite some time now. After moving from ColdFusion to Railo and upgrading IIS6 to IIS7.5 etc I have a problem with downloading and opening docx files (and some 'pdf-files') in Chrome and Internet Explorer. In Firefox everything still works fine.

The code I'm using (for docx files)

```
<cfset fileInfo=#getfileinfo(thefile)#>
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=""#thefilename#"""  charset="utf-8">
<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#fileInfo.size#">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" file="#thefile#">
<cfabort/>
```

For other file types I only use a different `<cfcontent type="">;` I already tried to use different mime-types (even application/unknown) but nothing works..

For ASP I found solutions that forcing `response.END` works for corrupted docx files...but `<cfabort/>` isn't doing the same trick

Anyone any ideas?

In the mean time:
the wierd thing is when I save the same file to disk from Chrome it's several kb's bigger (and cant be opened) than the same file downloaded through Firefox and Safari (which can be opened and have the exact FileInfo.size on the disk). 
Internet Explorer is not downloading the file at all...I get the message Save or Open, but no matter what i select nothing happens....
I tried to compare all the values from Fiddler but I'm not seeing any differences.

Comment: Try putting the abort immediately after the cfcontent? (i.e. without the linebreak you currently have)

Comment: hi Peter - tried that already - no effect;

Comment: Could anything in IIS or Tomcat be messing things up - i guess not because it's working in Firefox?

Comment: What exactly happens? Do you get any HTTP Protocol Violation errors when downloading when Fiddler is running?

Comment: no - i dont see anything wierd in Fiddler. The download seems to go well, but when i open the document i get a 'cant open document' kind-of error. Saving first and then opening doesnt change that. When doing the same in Firefox...no problem whatsoever...

Comment: ok - i found something wierd...i saved the same document in Firefox and Chrome and checked the size of the file. in Firefox the filesize is exactly the same as the Content-length; in Chrome it's about 5kb larger....?? so i guess there is more information being send....from where? i tried adding <cfcontent reset="yes"> but no effect

Comment: i opened up the raw data and see a bunch of white-space being added at the end in the response of Chrome

Comment: I checked the behaviour for pdf's aswell...same - all files downloaded through Chrome are a couple of kb's larger - ofcourse messing up the files in some cases

Comment: Make sure you've got **`output=false`** on cfcomponent tag _AND_ all the cffunctions for all relevant CFCs, including Application.cfc, and if you have an **onError**, make sure it doesn't do anything when cfabort is called.

Answer (score 1):

A work-around for this problem that i just implemented and which works:

- make a (temp-)copy of the file in a web-accessible directory
- cflocation to that file

Ofcourse far from ideal - but it will do as short-term solution